# How to Record an Audio and Play in QML?

Tags: qt, audio, qml

I am trying an application where i kept three buttons one for play,record and stop.
 When i press the record button,it should start record the audio by me. and after stopping it,when i play it.it should retrieve the recorded audio from the file,where it is stored.
I have tried using this link below,but could not find any solution.

https://projects.developer.nokia.com/audiorecorder/changeset/67519324bc6ea96ef956dec1b494eb3a5417402b

Can anyone find me a solution for this.I am badly in need of this solution!!!
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you should call the phonon's MediaSource/MediaObject classes to do it inthe back end.

```
#include <phonon/MediaObject>
#include <phonon/MediaSource>
```

Phonon::MediaObject *mobj....;

I dont know how QML is written but this is how you get to play media files in Qt.

Comment: Read from the Qt's own help file. Its too awesome.I learned it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your link seems to have a solution for Symbian only.

One general thing: There is no recording API for QML. But there are C++ classes in [QtMobility Multimedia](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/multimedia.html) which do what you want to do, you just need to export APIs to QML (that's what you can learn from the example in your link)